# Как сделать плавный переход между Activity?

Tags: activity

Как сделать плавными, более эффектными переходы от одного `Activity` к другому?

Comment: На сколько фантазии хватит. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определить анимацию перехода. Например так:

**res/anim/slidein.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

**res/anim/slideout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

**SomeActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidein, R.anim.slideout);
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое. мне очень пригодилось.